# How to get value if div is focused in jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Here I am having one div and one input text. I can get the input element value which is focused, but couldn't get the div value.

If I use `.val()`, I can get the input text value.
If I use `.html()`, I can get div element value.

But, I need the value of whatever is focused.

HTML

```
<div class="tab_common tab_addclass" tabindex="-1">4</div>
    <input class="text-input tab_addclass" id="other-input"/>
    <button type="button" id="btn">Validate</button>
```

JS

```
$(document).on ('click', '.tab_addclass', function(){
    $('.tab_addclass').each(function() {
        if($(this).hasClass('tab_focus'))
        {
            suc_flg=1;
            $(this).removeClass('tab_focus');
        }
    });
    $(this).addClass('tab_focus');

});
$(document).on ('click', '#btn', function(){
    alert($('.tab_focus').val());
});
```

CSS

```
.tab_focus {
    border: 2px solid #7ECC27;
    background-color: #F2F2F2;
}
.tab_common{
 border: 2px solid #d4d4d4;
    border-radius: 4px;  
    cursor: pointer;
}
div {
    background: #fff;
    margin: 20px;
}
div:focus {
    border: 2px solid #7ECC27;
}
```

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/t4zp1k0s/)

Comment: You cannot get value of div using `.val()` because val only for `type=text`

Comment: `tabindex="-1"` remove it, it makes it unselectable.

Comment: ok Jai but, How can I get the focused value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Updated** answer that returns the value of the most recently focused div or input following a button click:

```
$(document).on('click', '#btn', function () {
    var focusExist = $(".focus").length;
    if (focusExist) {
        $focus = $(".focus");

        if ($focus.hasClass("tab_common")) {
            var tabValue = $focus.text();
            alert(tabValue);
        } else {
            var inputValue = $focus.val();
            alert(inputValue);
        }
    }

});

$(document).on('focus', '.tab_addclass', function () {
    $(".focus").removeClass("focus");
    $(this).addClass("focus");
});
```

[Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jyrkim/t4zp1k0s/4/)

Comment: Here, I can't get the value of input text. I need to do this when button clicked. Whichever div or input type is focused, I need to get the value

Comment: Same problem, I can't get the input text value. And also I need to do this on button click.

Comment: @UIDesigner, ups I noticed that my Fiddle didn't update properly a moment ago - sorry. I updated the Fiddle again. And now the input field value can be obtained after a button click. Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/jyrkim/t4zp1k0s/4/

Comment: Thats it! Kudos jyrkim

Comment: Is this correct way to do this? $('.tab_focus').html()||$('.tab_focus').val()

Answer (score 2):

```js
$(document).on ('click', '.tab_addclass', function(){
    $('.tab_addclass').each(function() {
        if($(this).hasClass('tab_focus'))
        {
            suc_flg=1;
            $(this).removeClass('tab_focus');
        }
    });
    $(this).addClass('tab_focus');
    
});
$(document).on ('click', '#btn', function(){
    var test = $('.tab_focus').html()||$('.tab_focus').val()
    alert(test);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="tab_common tab_addclass" tabindex="-1">4</div>
<input class="text-input tab_addclass" id="other-input"/>
<button type="button" id="btn">Validate</button>
```

Comment: I need to assign the value to some variable. Is OR operator is the right way to do that?

Comment: Yes It's correct way. You can do this to get value of either `input` or `div` text

Answer (score 1):

You have to loop through your elements and check if it is `div` then get the text otherwise take the input value:

```js
$(document).on ('click', '#btn', function(){
  var val = {};
  $('.tab_addclass').each(function(){
     if($(this).is('div')){
         val.div = this.textContent;
     }else{
         val.input = this.value;
     }
  });
  $('p').text(JSON.stringify(val));
});
```

```css
p{background:black; color:white;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="tab_common tab_addclass" tabindex="-1">4</div>
<input class="text-input tab_addclass" id="other-input" value='input value' />
<button type="button" id="btn">Validate</button>
<br><br><br><br>
<p></p>
```

Comment: This is not working if I click button, I wrote button event and make the variable as global one

Comment: I tried, but getting two values undefined and original value

Comment: $('.tab_focus').html()||$('.tab_focus').val(). Is this the correct way ?

Comment: one more thing do you want to focus on div element or just want to have the text of the div and value of the input at the same time.

Comment: I need to get the value of input and text of div at the same time whichever is focused. Thats why I used addclass..whichever is having tab_focus class, I need to get the value on button click

Answer (score 0):

Use jQuery's keydown() funtion.

```
$(function(){
$('.tab_focus').keydown(function(){
alert($(this).val());
});
});
```

Comment: I need to get this on button click

Comment: So you can just simply get value on click, no need to add classes.

Answer (score 0):

Try this in your js

```
alert($('.tab_focus').val() | $('.tab_focus').html());
```